# Why artisan queue:work is running but not working on Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm stucked with a problem about Laravel queue worker using Elastic Beanstalk.

I'm using Github + CircleCI + Beanstalk in order to get my app deployed, all of this is working fine and with no problems, but the queue worker that is running on the instance is not pulling the available jobs on database (all the .env variables are well setted up, to use database for queues and so on).

I have configured a hook to restart queue worker and start it again on .ebextensions hooks, so this process is being run when the deploy finishes:

```
...
...
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_workers.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      php /var/app/current/artisan queue:restart
      php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work --queue=default --tries=2 &
...
...
```

**The very odd situation here, is that, if I ssh into the EB instance (I have only one), I see the worker running fine, but that worker is not pulling jobs from database** that are available to be processed:

[image: Queue worker running on Beanstalk EC2 instance after a successful deploy]

**BUT, if I kill the worker process, and then manually run exactly the same command, it works perfect** and pull all jobs:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone can figure out why this could be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a heads up, you probably should not be running queue:work as root.

Comment: The  problem could be how you're sending the task to the background.  It expects to still direct output to the the terminal.  Try using nohup and redirecting stdout and stderr.

Comment: @devon but if it works running the queue as root on the console, it should work with the hook: they are exactly the same command.

Comment: @devon I tried with nohup and redirecting output, with no luck.

Comment: I mean, the security aspect of running any web app or worker as root is generally discouraged as root has access to do everything on your server.

Comment: When you redirected output, what was logged?  Did it get stuck on a specific step?

Comment: @Devon thank you for your help, finally, after a lots of tries, I solved it using SQS and this library: dusterio/laravel-aws-worker.